# Generating unique keys (filenames) for S3

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I'm writing a .NET Core web app that will be uploading files to an S3 bucket. I'm not sure how to safely generate keys (filenames) for the bucket, however. What should I do for generating a random key to avoid collisions?

I've read [Request Rate and Performance Considerations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html) from AWS, so I'm familiar with the idea of randomness for performance reasons, but I'm not sure about randomness for avoiding collisions. I don't know what is considered random enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can guarantee not to clash by prepending a GUID to each key.